# Good way to search a directory for files that follow a specific naming convention?

Tags: c#

My application allows clients to specify 80 images manually that will be utilized later on. However, I also offer functionality to automatically find and load these image files, as long as they follow a specific naming convention.

For example, the naming convention for these files is as follows:

`*ClientName*_*ImageName*.png`

Only PNG files are allowed, and `ImageName` is application-defined set of names. `ClientName` is ignored as it is defined client-side.

I am in the process of adding more images, and realize that my current way of handling this is not feasible.

Currently I get all files in a specified directory that have the PNG extension.

Then, my code is as follows (an example):

```
if (StringContains(currFile, "Tree"))
{
    // assign image "Tree"
}
else if (StringContains(currFile, "Bush"))
{
    // assign image "Bush"
}

...etc
```

My `StringContains` function simply does a `String.IndexOf(currFile, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` and returns true if the result is `>= 0`.

The first problem with this approach is the endless if/else if statements. It is not manageable.

The second issue is if I have an image that is called `TreeMaple`. I *now* need to change my if statement for finding the "Tree" image to this:

```
if (StringContains(currFile, "Tree") && !StringContains(currFile, "Maple"))
```

And you can imagine how crazy this gets when you add more image names like "TreeMapleFall", "TreeMapleWinter", "TreeMapleWinterSnow", etc., which is what I plan on doing.

How can I make this code more simple, maintainable and easier to read?

Comment: Have you looked into regex expressions? You could specify all files of type PNG with something like this:    Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\", "*.png");

Comment: I think it's unclear how your image names are formatted. If you're just checking a string to contain another string, won't you get issues with coincidental names, like `HoldingSomeMapleSyrupInFrontOfThisTree`? You might want a true parser rather than contains checks. For example: match the first word (`Tree`) then move on to the next set of words `MapleWinter`: match the first word (`Maple`)...

Comment: Also, if you make it clear what `// assign image "x"` is, then maybe we could find a generalized solution for the assigning that allows for an approach that doesn't depend on your hierarchy (and therefore doesn't have to be updated with your hierarchy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of this may be easier:

```
string pattern = @"[^_]+_([^_]+)\.png";  // Regex pattern to capture *ImageName*
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = regex.Match(currFile);
if (match.Success)                       // If image abides by the format
{
    switch (match.Value) {               // Switch on the *ImageName*
        case "Tree":
            // Logic
            break;
        case "Bush":
            // Logic
            break;
        case "Maple":
            // Logic
            break;
    }
}
```

or using delegates:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> imageActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
if (match.Success && imageActions.ContainsKey(match.Value))   // If image abides by the format and a delegate exists for handling that image name
    imageActions[match.Value]();

// usage
imageActions.Add("Tree", () => { /* Logic */ });
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the first solution you have proposed. However, I'd still like to "break free" from using hardcoded literal strings (in your switch-case clause), so perhaps I could loop through a List of ImageNames instead to find a match? Your second solution fixes this though, maybe I'll just implement that.

Comment: yes exactly! also thats why i proposed maybe a dictionary of `imageNames` as keys and delegates for handling!

Comment: Implemented your second proposal, it works great! Although I did need to change one line - `match.Value` needs to be replaced with `match.Groups[1].Value`, as the former returns the original string in it's entirety (in this case, the file path).